# Is an easy proof of an interesting result worth publishing?

Tags: soft-question, journals

I am a Phd math student, and I was wondering what was the general consensus on what is publishable and what is not.

I've come here with an example in mind which should give some insight. I recently proved an inequality which was needed for some other work, and it is a very crucial inequality. The proof generalises an already well known inequality, but in a quite easy way. I mean that the generalisation is both very easy to obtain and does not use any new machinery, it's obtained by just a modification of the proof of the original one. And I mean that if the authors put a remark below their proof saying "here do this and that instead of what we did, and the generalisation is easy", everyone would see how to do it.

Now, the proof is very short and basically follows the old one, but I thought it may be worth publishing because the result, although easy to obtain, is technically new and potentially of interest (again, it's not a surprising result, but still). But the proof is not interesting, it's basically a copy. I'll talk with the supervisor to see what to do, but I was curious about different takes more experienced mathematicians have on this. Would you put the result out there (obviously saying that you used the old proof almost unchanged) or leave it be?

EDIT: Apparently the generalisation is not known. I mean, people working on this are like "yeah of course in some way you can do it, 100%", but probably would need to at least think a bit on how to do it

Comment: Could be suitable for American Math. Monthly or similar.

Comment: The inequality is well known, but in its own niche, I thought AMM was more for recreational math or topics of interest to the "big" public? Also, for the future: is AMM better in a cv than a mid-low tier research journal?

Comment: There is no way to answer this question in the abstract.  The correct solution is to ask your PhD advisor.  Answering this kind of question is their job!

Comment: Based on your description, it seems unlikely any good journal would publish it. I would try to post it to arXiv.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a place to publish it, when you wrote "...which was needed for some other work." Publish it with that other work! If you want to highlight it, make it it's own section titled "A generalization of the inequality among doowizzles".

Comment: @PerAlexandersson The Monthly is intended for an undergraduate audience. If it's a technical result that is not likely to be of interest to a general audience, then the Monthly is not a suitable venue. Some people think of the Monthly as a "journal of minor research," but that is not accurate.

Comment: @TimothyChow I figured if the inequality in question is well-known, as in the AM-GM, and the proof of the generalization is elementary, then it might be suitable.

Comment: @TimothyChow : "The Monthly is intended for an undergraduate audience" -- My impression is different. In particular, in the MAA 
[Guide for Referees](https://maa.org/press/periodicals/guide-for-referees) we find the following: "Making articles inviting usually means aiming them at the right audience, which ought to be mathematicians who are novices in the subject. For example, authors writing about analysis should think about what they would say to the algebraist down the hall or to a graduate student in the program."

Comment: @IosifPinelis The very first issue in 1894 said "Most of our existing Journals deal almost exclusively with subjects beyond the reach of the average student or teacher of Mathematics or at least with subjects with which they are not familiar, and little, if any space, is devoted to the solution of problems. While not neglecting the higher fields of mathematical investigation, THE AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL MONTHLY will also endeavor to reach the average mathematician." Implicitly, this is saying that the subject matter should be accessible (though not exclusively directed) to "the average student."

Comment: @TimothyChow the target audience of the Monthly has changed somewhat since 1894. While it still is committed to articles that are written well and for a broad audience, pieces aimed at graduate students are considered. I was told this by someone with recent experience on the editorial side of the Monthly.

Comment: @KConrad I find this conversation interesting and actually quite relevant, since I'm currently contemplating an expository article whose content is "elementary" but whose "maturity level" is higher than that of an undergraduate. I thought it wouldn't be suitable for the *Monthly*, but you and Iosif have persuaded me to reconsider.

Comment: You should listen to advisor, but do not have to follow his advice.
If you still think it worth sharing with other people, then publish.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first answer to this sort of thing is to always talk with your adviser who will know more about the state of the subfield than you will, and will definitely know the specifics more than people here.

However, that said, my general inclination is to say that things like this should be published. First, it is often the case that something that seems obvious to you is not as obvious as one might think otherwise. Our own ideas often seem more more obvious since we have been thinking about them a lot. Second, having extensions even small extensions can be useful for other people have as actual references. Third, at the vast majority of points in one's career you will not be hurt by publishing a mostly straightforward result, and that's especially the case if one is still doing one's PhD. Worse case scenario, you put it on the arxiv and then after sending it to a journal they reject it as too obvious. (And to echo Andy's comment below do not put it on the arxiv without consulting with your adviser.)

That said, it is possible that the ideal place is not to publish it by itself, but possibly to publish it as part of some paper where one is proving larger results. But this again falls very much into a talk-to-your-adviser thing.

Comment: Just to be clear since you didn't say it outright: the OP should definitely not write a paper on this and put it on the arXiv without first getting the approval of their advisor.

Comment: @AndyPutman Yes, you are absolutely correct there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is an easy proof of an interesting result worth publishing?

Probably not (but "probably" doesn't mean "certainly", so, as others said, ask your adviser).

The issue is that as a PhD student, your perspective on what counts as "interesting" and what counts as "easy" is likely to be different than the perspective of the sort of more experienced mathematicians who make up the intended readership of your prospective publication, and who would referee it. As one gains experience in mathematics, what one once regarded as "easy" will often get downgraded to "completely trivial" (and what one regarded as "somewhat nontrivial" gets downgraded to "easy", what one regarded as "hard" gets downgraded to "somewhat nontrivial", and so on).
Similarly, what one has regarded as "interesting" as a PhD student will quite often later be revised to "mildly noteworthy" or even further to "not interesting".

Basically, this evolution in one's perception of how interesting/clever/publishable/etc one's ideas are is not only common and natural, but always points in the same direction. So if you think your result is easy *now*, just wait a few years...

Comment: You make it sound like people become more clever with age. Not completely trivial.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I would rather say that familiarity breeds contempt. A clever idea seems less clever the more times one sees it applied. This is not a logical truth, but it is a psychological truth. Once an argument becomes "standard," it becomes less publishable, no matter how clever it was the first time around.

Comment: @FedorPetrov well, if it was completely trivial I wouldn’t bother publishing it as a mathoverflow answer…